# Anorm with Java 8 Date/Time API

Tags: scala, datetime, playframework, playframework-2.3, anorm

I try to save timestamp field to postgresql using anorm. In scala code date/time stored as instance of java.time.Instant (someTime variable)

```
DB.withConnection() { implicit c => 
    SQL("INSERT INTO t_table(some_time) values ({someTime})").on('someTime -> someTime)
}
```

But anorm can't work with it now (Play 2.3.7).

What is the best way to make it work?

Comment: See https://github.com/playframework/anorm/pull/10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe most people are using JodaTime so might explain why its missing. If its not part of Anorm you can write your own converter.

This is untested but it would look something like below

```
import java.time.Instant
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import java.util.TimeZone

import anorm._

object InstantAnormExtension {
  val dateFormatGeneration = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss-Z")

  implicit def rowToDateTime: Column[Instant] = Column.nonNull { (value, meta) =>
    val MetaDataItem(qualified, nullable, clazz) = meta
    value match {
      case ts: java.sql.Timestamp => Right(ts.toInstant)
      case d: java.sql.Date => Right(d.toInstant)
      case str: java.lang.String => Right(Instant.from(dateFormatGeneration.parse(str)))
      case _ => Left(TypeDoesNotMatch("Cannot convert " + value + ":" + value.asInstanceOf[AnyRef].getClass) )
    }
  }
  implicit val dateTimeToStatement = new ToStatement[Instant] {
    def set(s: java.sql.PreparedStatement, index: Int, aValue: Instant): Unit = {
      if(aValue == null) {
        s.setTimestamp(index, null)
      } else {
        s.setTimestamp(index, java.sql.Timestamp.from(aValue) )
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: yep. with java 8 now seems more and more people will forget about joda-time. strategically-wise. but maybe not. log4j is till in use f.e.