# Scala date/time best practices

Tags: scala, datetime

I write scala/play/postgresql web service and try to find the best practices/libraries for work with date/time data in scala.

I see for two solutions:

1) [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) (Still very good lib, but JSR-310 Is already here. Almost a year!).

2) The [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) built into Java 8 ([JSR-310](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310)). From Joda-Time founder, it must be right to use it. But it is not compatible with today libraries and frameworks. For example [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28031715/1768378) forced me to ask this question.

But may be it is some another solutions in Scala world?

Comment: FYI : https://github.com/nscala-time/nscala-time

Comment: Yes, i've seen this wrap over JodaTime. Is it really best practice, and supported by Play anorm, and others?

Comment: You might see a change when people start using Scala 2.12. It will require Java 8. Right now with Scala 2.11 and hence play on Scala needing to support Java 6 I believe library developers will be avoiding a dependency on Java 8 libraries. This doesn't mean you should avoid it if this is in your application code.

Comment: Joda-Time and java.time share some key ideas but have different architectures. Each has strengths over the other. Each has features the other lacks. Fortunately, you can use both in your app; just be careful with your `import` as they share a few class names. See [ThreeTen Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/), a project adding features to java.time.

Answer (score 2):

There are no especially well-established or "standard" scala date/time libraries (though as mentioned in the comments, nscala-time is a minor argument for using Joda Time, as I'm not aware of a similar wrapper for JSR-310). Make the same choice you would in Java, there's no real scala-specific consideration here.

Comment: There is also https://github.com/reactivecodes/scala-time wrapping JSR-310.